# shopify nodejs app argument str must be a string

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I developed a test shopify app and all works fine. If I installed the app and get redirected I get successfull data. But if I am going to shopify now and click on my installed app I get error:

```
argument str must be a string
```

of course, when anyone want to install the app but first visit my page on myPage.de/shopify I create a nonce() function and set it in a state, when he redirect to shopify to install the app and goes back he comes to myPage.de/callback/shopify, so then the cookie are always there, but if I go to my apps on shopify and then click on my app, I get the error on cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state "argument str must be a string". So how can I fix it ?

```
app.get('/shopify', (req, res) => {
  const shop = req.query.shop;

  if (!shop) { return res.status(400).send('no shop')}

  const state = nonce();

  const installShopUrl = buildInstallUrl(shop, state, buildRedirectUri())

  res.cookie('state', state) // should be encrypted in production
  res.redirect(installShopUrl);
});

app.get('/shopify/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { shop, code, state } = req.query;

  const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state;


  if (state !== stateCookie) { return res.status(403).send('Cannot be verified')}

  const { hmac, ...params } = req.query
  const queryParams = querystring.stringify(params)
  const hash = generateEncryptedHash(queryParams)

  if (hash !== hmac) { return res.status(400).send('HMAC validation failed')}

  try {
    const data = {
      client_id: shopifyApiPublicKey,
      client_secret: shopifyApiSecretKey,
      code
    };
    const tokenResponse = await fetchAccessToken(shop, data)

    const { access_token } = tokenResponse.data

    const shopData = await fetchShopData(shop, access_token)
    res.send(shopData.data.shop)

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('something went wrong')
  }
});

///////////// Start the Server /////////////

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state;
```

`req.headers.cookie` can be null or undefined;

change to

```
const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || "")?.state;

if (state !== stateCookie) { return res.status(403).send('Cannot be verified')}
```

Comment: hey thanks but then I cannot be verified when I am click on my shopify app because state !== stateCookie <-

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the cookie.  Cookie is not used for verification, session is.  If it is missing, your code should create one during the log in process.